# A way to examine a separate java application's GUI buttons/labels/etc

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm looking for a program, application, or some way to examine a java application, and be able to view its GUI information. This would include buttons, labels, panels, and list information. Ideally you could examine things by using the mouse pointer, and either hovering over an object or clicking on it. The separate program or application could display things like type of object, object name, and position of object in a console or a window.

I've found some applications that can examine a java application if it's using the Java Access Bridge, but I'm looking for a way that does not require the target java application to have the JAB.

Java Native Interface (JNI) allows you to get mouse clicks, positioning, and keyboard presses, but it does not appear to return information, like button names, inside a java application. Any ideas?

Comment: I am wondering the exact same thing at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Answers to this question will be highly subjective, depending on the type of GUI technology used and the personal views of the answering person.

That being said, when I do JavaFX development, I use [ScenicView.](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) It works really well in my experience and can be loaded a number of different ways. It has most of the features you mentioned and displays a ton of data about the GUI objects, as well as highlighting the selected object's boundaries.

Comment: There should be something that works for any guy, no?

Comment: No, because different GUI technologies work differently under the hood. If youre doing Swing, you need a Swing tool, if youre doing JavaFX, you need an FX tool.